# Oracle legacy exp/imp: ORA-25179: invalid PCTTHRESHOLD storage option value

Tags: oracle, import, export

I exported Oracle schema with *exp* command.
Then, using the dump file created by *exp* I tried to *imp* schema to a new one in the same database.

Commands were pretty straightforward:

```
exp userid=user1/pass1@dbname owner=user1 statistics=none file=user1_exp.dmp log=user1_exp.log 
imp userid=user2/pass2@dbname FROMUSER=user1 TOUSER=user2 file=user1_exp.dmp log=user2_imp.log
```

And got the error related to  PCTTHRESHOLD 0 which should be a positive integer.
[image]

However, in the original table definition it was "PCTTHRESHOLD 50":
[image]

Is there something I'm missing in *exp* command parameters?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: It could be a bug. If exporting/importing to the same instance, why not use datapump? The exp/imp utilities have been deprecated for a long time.

Comment: I know, but working with legacy software where I need a dump in exp format

Comment: It shouldn't matter that your software is legacy - your software isn't consuming the export file, Oracle is. Please try expdp/impdp instead. I doubt Oracle is even maintaining exp/imp anymore, and even if they are keeping them for backwards compatibility, they aren't getting rigorously bug tested with newer dictionary structures.

Comment: Do you have at least one row in every table being exports? I see the option `SEGMENT CREATION DEFERRED`, and one common problem with `exp` is that it was built before deferred segment creation existed. The `exp` tool sometimes looks at segment metadata instead of object metadata, and things can be missing from `exp` output if the segment was never created.

Comment: @JonHeller - Thank you for the useful insight. Indeed, some tables in the exported schema are empty, particularly the table in question (C_ACTION_MARKETING_STRP) is empty. 
Could you please tell if know of any way to tell *exp* tool to always use object metadata? I guess there is no such tweak but it is worth asking.

Comment: Found a way to workaround the issue - "alter table <tablename> allocate extent".
See https://www.dba-oracle.com/t_oracle_deferred_segment_creation.htm

Answer (score 1):

*exp* tool is not working correctly with tables that have no segments allocated. It's a [known issue](https://www.dba-oracle.com/t_oracle_deferred_segment_creation.htm) that can be fixed like this:

```
alter table <tablename> allocate extent;
```